# Jekyll with GitHub Enterprise?

Tags: github, jekyll, github-pages, github-enterprise

I see this question in a couple of places, but no clear answers or a resolution.  I am using an enterprise github - `https://github.(mycompany).com`

I have a jekyll theme which is still resolving to `https://github.com`.

I thought there should be a variable somewhere in `_config.yml`.

Does anybody know how to do this?

Its showing up in the image links, editme links, etc.

Comment: Please provide more details regarding the statement *"I have a jekyll theme which is still resolving to `https://github.com`"*. Are you using the `remote_theme` setting?

Comment: No, this is a downloaded (mirrored from another repo) theme.  Our gemfile is standard  ```source "https://rubygems.org"

# to publish on github page
gem 'github-pages', group: :jekyll_plugins

# to publich without github page
#gem "jekyll"
```

Comment: Still not clear.. Can I access the repository? If not can you post a screenshot of the error or the page showing the wrong URL..?

Comment: hmm - I mirrored this theme/repo (https://github.com/tomjoht/documentation-theme-jekyll).  I want to use it with a enterprise git so the `editme` link now resolves to https://github.com and it needs to shift to https://github.ibm.com  Just not sure where that is being defined.

Answer (score 0):

All you had to do was search for it on GitHub itself.

The `Edit me` link you mentioned in the comment above is [this line](https://github.com/tomjoht/documentation-theme-jekyll/blob/b3c5acf1daa9d56d2f7f5774ee70a5454248e7f2/_layouts/page.html#L44):